# Json converting java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I use Spring boot 2 default configuration to deserialize from json to object. Can it deserialize json if it has more key:value pair than java object? Like this:

json:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jane",
  "age": 21
}
```

Java class:

```
public class ClientResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Java object has not age property, but json has.

Does it convert correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just add the following annotation on your class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"age"})
public class ClientResponse {}
```

If you want to ignore any unknown properties:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

[Reference info](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what if inverse? If in json has not key that have in java object?

Comment: @qwerty Jackson works by creating an instance of your class and then copying properties. If you don't have it in JSON, it will stay the default (usually null).